# PixelFormat JavaFX scaling

Tags: graphics, javafx

I am trying to capture a portion of my JavafX canvas. However, only the operating system screen from below is captured, and the scaling is all wrong. I thought the glass.ui robot was supposed to work with Javafx. Also, I'm confused by how to calculate the scanLine. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

```
    com.sun.glass.ui.Robot robot = com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().createRobot();
    Pixels p  =robot.getScreenCapture(1,1,1000,1000);
    Buffer buf = p.getPixels();
    java.nio.IntBuffer intBuffer = (IntBuffer) buf;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1001*1001];
    int i=0;
    while(buf.hasRemaining()){
        bytes[i++] = (byte) intBuffer.get();
    }
    PixelFormat<ByteBuffer> pixelFormat = PixelFormat.getByteRgbInstance();
    PixelWriter pw = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().getPixelWriter();
    pw.setPixels(1, 1, 1000, 1000, pixelFormat, bytes, 1, 1000);
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you are not just using the built-in snapshot function?

Comment: Because this is a test, and eventually, I want to be able to capture an exact (small) area of screen.

Comment: Try SwingFXUitls.toFXImage .. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#toFXImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20javafx.scene.image.WritableImage) maybe its an problem in your converting